# Lambda expression not behaving as expected

Tags: c#, .net, lambda

I'm trying to construct a lambda expression that will match elements of one array with a second.  Below is a simplified version of this query:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] listOne = new string[] { "test1", "test2", "test3" };
        MyClass[] listTwo = new MyClass[] { new MyClass("test1") };

        string[] newVals = listOne.Where(p => listTwo.Select(e => e.Name).Equals(p)).ToArray();

        //string[] newVals2 = listOne.Intersect(listTwo.Select(t => t.Name)).ToArray();
    }

    class MyClass
    {
        public MyClass(string name)
        {
            Name = name;
        }
        public string Name {get; set;}
    }
}
```

I would expect `newVals` to return an array of 1 value, but it's empty.  I realise that uncommenting myVals2 would achieve the same result, but the lists of classes differ more fundamentally than shown.

Comment: `listTwo.Select(e => e.Name).Equals(p)`? I don't think that's doing what you intended...

Comment: I believe you are trying to do a join. So instead of using the where clause, use a the regualr linq join (it is clearer as to what you are trying to achieve).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `Equals` but you should use `Contains`. You are checking wheter `IEnumerable<>` is equal to `p`, but you want to check if `IEnumerable<>` contains `p`, so replace:

```
string[] newVals = listOne.
                   Where(p => listTwo.Select(e => e.Name).Equals(p)).
                   ToArray();
```

with

```
string[] newVals = listOne.
                   Where(p => listTwo.Select(e => e.Name).Contains(p)).
                   ToArray();
```

Comment: You want to be careful using this. listTwo will be iterated for each entry in listOne.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
string[] listOne = new string[] { "test1", "test2", "test3" };
        MyClass[] listTwo = new MyClass[] { new MyClass("test1") };

        string[] newVals = listOne
                       .Where(p => listTwo.Select(e => e.Name).Contains(p))
                       .ToArray();
```

`listTwo.Select(e => e.Name)` is a `IEnumerable<string>`

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to perform a `Join` on the 2 collections.

```
var q = 
  listOne
  .Join(
    listTwo,
    l2 => l2,
    l1 => l1.Name,
    (l2, l1) => new { l2, l1, });
```

You can change the selector (the last parameter) to suit your needs, if it's just values from listOne for example then have `(l2, l1) => l1`.

The other solutions will work, but maybe not as you would expect.

Using Linq-Objects Contains within a where clause will cause the entire of `listTwo` to be iterated **for each** entry in `listOne`.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
string[] newVals = listOne.Where(p => listTwo.Any(e => e.Name.Contains(p))).ToArray();
```

or to be more strict use `==` instead of `Contains`.

But if you want to obtain the items that are common between the 2 why not just call `.Intersect()`??

Comment: `Intersect` won't work because the sequences are not of the same type.  You need to use `Join`, which is why [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14525867/1159478) is the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to perform a join, technically you are better off simplifying your linq statement to use a join. An example is included below.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] listOne = new [] { "test1", "test2", "test3" };
        MyClass[] listTwo = new [] { new MyClass("test1") };

        string[] newVals = (from str1 in listOne
                           join str2 in  listTwo.Select(e => e.Name) on str1 equals str2
                           select str1).ToArray();
        foreach (var newVal in newVals)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(newVal);
        }

        //string[] newVals2 = listOne.Intersect(listTwo.Select(t => t.Name)).ToArray();
    }

    class MyClass
    {
        public MyClass(string name)
        {
            Name = name;
        }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```